# eclipseでvmlinux-gdb.pyを有効にする方法

Tags: linux, eclipse

qemuをつかってlinuxカーネルデバッグをします
linuxカーネルは4.2.6でconfigにGDB_SCRIPT=yとしています。
GDB_SCRIPT=yとしていますので、vmlinuxと同じディレクトリにvmlinux-gdb.pyへのリンクができます。
これにより、gdb起動時にvmlinux-gdb.pyが自動的に読み込まれ
lx-dmesg, lx-lsmod, lx-symbolなどのコマンドが使えるようになります。

linuxの起動はqemuを以下のコマンドで起動しています。

> qemu-system-x86_64 -hda Debian-jessie_amd64.qcow -m 4G -net nic,model=e1000 -net tap,ifname=tap-qemu0,script=no -s

-sオプションを付けていますので、target remote :1234でgdbに接続できます。

gdbの起動は以下のようにします。

> gdb vmlinux
>   target remote :1234

ここでlx-dmesgなどのコマンドが使用出来ています。

問題はここからです
これをeclipse CDTのGDB Hardware Debuggingを使用してeclipse上で実行するときです。
breakpointやcontinueなどのデバッグ機能はうまく動きます。
しかしながら、eclipseのgdbコンソールからlx-dmesgと入力しても
Undefined commandと言われて使うことができません

vmlinux-gdb.pyが自動で読み込まれていないようなのですが
これを読み込ませる方法をお教えください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決です。

EclipseのGDB Heardware DebuggingはGDBの起動の際に-nxオプションをつけて
~/.gdbinitを読み込みません。

~/.gdbinitにはpythonの自動ロードを許可するために

> set auto-load safe-path /

を含めていました。

しかし~/.gdbinitを読み込まないためset auto-load safe-path /が効かず
vmlinux-gdb.pyが自動で読み込まれていませんでした。

読み込ませるためにGDBの起動をgdb -x ~/.gdbinitとすることで解決できました。